# How to get client ip in nodeJS on IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, express

I have created app in nodejs and deployed on IIS
I cannot get ips of clients.
i have tried many modules and SO answers ,but still no use.

server code

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var requestIp = require('request-ip');
 var ip = require("ip");

 var get_ip = require('ipware')().get_ip;


 //app.enable('trust proxy');
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     var op = {
         op: [
             req.headers["X-Forwarded-For"],
             req.headers["x-forwarded-for"],
             req.client.remoteAddress,
             ip.address(),
             requestIp.getClientIp(req),
             get_ip(req),
             req.ip,
             req.ips,

             1122 //hard coded number.
         ]
     }

     res.send(op);
 });

 var server = app.listen(4000, function() {


     var host = server.address().address;
     var port = server.address().port;

     console.log('Example app listening at http' + host + port);
 });
```

on deployment on iis this is answer

```
      {
      "op": [null, 
             null,
             null, 
             "216.157.123.123",  //server ip
             null, 
             { "clientIp": "127.0.0.1", "clientIpRoutable": false },
             null,
             [], 
             1122]
  }
```

do i need to configure something on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old request but in case it helps another, it turns out that, by default, iisnode does not forward a request header's `x-forwarded-for` information.  To get the client's IP address forwarded, in web.config, you have to add to the `<iisnode />` section:  `enableXFF="true"`.

More information can be found at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/94.
I hope this helps! (Sure helped me!)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install "Enhanced Logging" or "Advanced Logging add-on"?

http://loadbalancer.org/blog/iis-and-x-forwarded-for-header